# Symfony convert entity to json format by looping foreach

Tags: php, json, symfony, entity, response

I have a little REST API in my project. And ofcourse i use json as my return data to work with.

I am using symfony in the backend and angularJs in the frontend. At the moment i convert my entity to json by looping true my result and filling an data array to return as json.

EXAMPLE:

```
public function getAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $warehouseId = $this->get('session')->get('warehouse');
    $warehouse = $em->getRepository('BubbleMainBundle:Warehouse')->find($warehouseId);

    $trip = $em->getRepository('BubbleMainBundle:Trip')->find($id);

    $data = array(
        'id'     => $trip->getId(),
        'driver' => $trip->getDriver(),
        'status' => $trip->getStatus(),
        'date'   => $trip->getPlanningDate()->format('Y-m-d')
    );

    if ( count($trip->getStops()) > 0 ) {

        foreach($trip->getStops() as $stop)
        {
            $data['assignedStops'][] = array(
                'id' => $stop->getId(),
                'status' => $stop->getStatus(),
                'date' => $stop->getDeliveryDate()->format('Y-m-d'),
                'sort' => $stop->getSort(),
                'company' => array(
                    'name' => $stop->getToCompany()->getName(),
                    'lat' => $stop->getToCompany()->getLat(),
                    'lng' => $stop->getToCompany()->getLng(),
                    'address' => $stop->getToCompany()->getAddress(),
                    'zip' => $stop->getToCompany()->getZip()
                ),
            );
        }
    } else {

        $data['assignedStops'][] = '';
    }

    $response = new jsonResponse();
    $response->setData($data);

    return $response;
}
```

This works. But sometimes i have have (google chrome timeline) waiting responses of 6 seconds for just a simple query and json response.

Is looping true the entity to much? Or do i need another approach for converting my entities to json format?

thx anthony,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 5.4 or above then considering using the `JsonSerializable` interface with your entities:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php

This will allow you to control how your entities are converted to JSON which will allow you to call `json_encode` directly on your entities without having to loop through and convert them to arrays.

As for the performance issue you'd need to profile your script to find out where the performance bottleneck is. From looking at your code one potential issue that you might want to look into is to make sure you are fetching all the data in your original query (i.e stops and companies) and you are not executing additional queries in the foreach loop to fetch the missing stop and company data.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you (since you are using Symfony2 as a backend and you need an API) to definitely try out this [bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRest)... It's easy to use and to setup and as an extra you can also generate a nice [documentation](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) for it.
It will speed up your development and code.